# How to import plain JS into TypeScript (without Typings)

Tags: typescript

We have a project using TypeScript with ts-loader in Webpack, for most of the things we've used now there were type definitions in Definitely Types (via `typings`), but not for the one we wanted to use now: [`redux-auth`](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth).

At first I had no `module` defined in tsconfig.json and importing it via

```
import { EmailSignInForm } from "redux-auth/bootstrap-theme"
```

resulted in `Cannot find module`. Then we read that using the CommonJS notation could help, but it didn't since TS didn't know about the members of the imported module (`Property 'EmailSignInForm' does not exist on type '{}'`). Using the relative path doesn't do anything useful as well.

Also I've read in [this article about TS 1.8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta/) that it should now support plain JS files, but doesn't explain exactly how. allowJs is enabled.

How do I import that module? Thanks!

This is our webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var fail = require('webpack-fail-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './static/files/app/main.tsx',

  output: {
    path: './static/files/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ]
  },

  devtool: 'source-map',

  plugins: [
    fail,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      //Promise: 'exports?global.Promise!es6-shim',
      fetch: 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    })
  ]
};
```

And our tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

(The `"module": "commonjs"` was temporary to test the CommonJS notation)

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so if I `declare var require: any` and use the relative path in `require()` I can import it, although I doubt that this is the intended way. Funnily now I get this message from Webpack:

```
WARNING in ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js
Critical dependencies:
9:12-34 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34

ERROR in ./~/iconv-lite/encodings/tables/gb18030-ranges.json
Module parse failed: ./node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings/tables/gb18030-ranges.json Line 1: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Comment: That is the intended way from what I gather

Comment: My answer here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack/40416826#40416826

Answer (score 6):

```
# declarations.d.ts
declare module '*';

# someFile.ts
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

If you have types for one module code completion should work and the compiler will assume you know what you are doing. I think ts loader should respect that as well. Please test and let me know.

Comment: I missed the fact that the `declare` statement had to be in a separate file initially. Adding a `declarations.d.ts` file containing `declare module 'libToInclude';` worked for me.

Comment: Idk what you mean. I didn't ask the question. I was just commenting to hopefully prevent others from spending a while trying to figure this out. I think I read through this answer too quickly as I was going through Google search results...