# How to import JS in TS with noImplicityAny and without allowJs

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Webpack and `@babel/typescript` to compile a mixed TypeScript and JavaScript project.

I'm using `--noImplicitAny` to encourage taking advantage of typing.

I'm not using `--allowJs` because my project is so big that it chokes the TypeScript compiler, and it destroys Visual Studio highlighting/Intellisense.

For un-typed npm modules, if I don't have time to add typings, I create a definition file to explicitly set its type to `any`. For example

**example.ts**

```
import * as elemDataset from 'elem-dataset';
```

**elem-dataset.ts**

```
declare module 'elem-dataset';
```

That satisfies the compiler. But for internal modules I haven't yet converted to TS...

```
import * as example from './example2';  // Where example2 is example2.ts
```

I get this error:

> Could not find a type declaration file for module './example2'. C:/blah/blah/blah/example2.js implicitly has 'any' type.

I've tried adding a type declaration, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438855/684776).

**example2.d.ts**

```
declare var example2: any;

declare module "example2" {
    export = example2;
}
```

But then I get this error:

> File C:/blah/blah/blah/example2.d.ts is not a module.

I've also tried `declare module '*';` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086348/684776), but I got the same error as above.

How can I explicitly set the import type of an internal JS file to any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out this is sufficient for my needs:

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as x from './example2';
```

I didn't try it at first, because I thought that comment would disable type checking for the whole file.

But using `@ts-ignore` just before the import allows me to enforce type checking for the rest of the project while ignoring a single JavaScript file until I have time to convert it.

Comment: I used this solution before for importing external Javascript library modules. One day I thought `@ts-ignore` looked distasteful and tried `allowJs` instead and a whole host of problem appears. Just stick with `@ts-ignore`